# Does React rerender child components if they become null via ternary operation?

Tags: reactjs

If we have a state called, `show`, which determines whether to display `<Child />` component. Does `<Child />` component re-render if its parent re-renders and `show` is still false?

```
{ show === true ? <Child /> : null }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following piece of code

```
{ condition ? <Component /> : null }
```

Can be interpreted as:

If a given `condition` asserts to `true` then render `Component` else render `null`.

Something will always be rendered, either `null` or an `instance` of `Component`. Now this one:

```
{ condition && <Component /> }
```

Doesn't render anything cause the interpreter will just stop when the first part of the logical operator (`&&`) returns `false` (cause you don't even need to check what comes after). So in this case nothing is rendered, not even `null`. It's worth mentioning that performance wise both are pretty much the same

Comment: So if the condition is false, null is rendered. Does null also cause performance issue?

Comment: Not at all the difference between render null and not render anything is negligible

Comment: Thanks! Are there any other methods to render components with conditions rather than using ternary?

Comment: Jsx doesn't support `if/else` statements. But If you wrap the logic inside a function which implements the conditional logic and returns the correspondent jsx you can implement your custom logic